# Primefaces Monaco Editor Auto Completion

Tags: primefaces, monaco-editor, primefaces-extensions

I Am Using Monaco Editor and i want to add personalised suggestions,
is there any way to achieve that

```
    <pe:monacoEditor id="monacoEditor" 
                     widgetVar="monacoEditor"
                     customThemes=""
                     editorOptions=""
                     value=""
                     width="100%" height="300px" 
                     autoResize="true">
                     </pe:monacoEditor>
```

Comment: This is probably a question better asked on PrimeFaces Extensions GitHub so blutorange can answer as he is the Monaco Editor expert.  Ask here: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues  I am not sure if he checks Stack Overflow.